# Matlab mysql jdbc memory leak w/database toolbox

Tags: mysql, matlab, jdbc, memory-leaks

I was running into a memory leak using mathworks' database toolbox with mysql.  If I was returning large amounts of data, eventually the I would get an out of memory error running out of java heap space.

I had seen this before and used the `com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Prepared` Statement and `com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet` driver calls myself.  When you do this, you have to be sure to call the `close()` methods of each of those, or else you have the same problem.

I remembered this today when mathworks shoddy object was hitting heap problems by just exec'ing the same query and fetching the results a few thousand times.  It turns out you can see the mysql jdbc objects in the mathworks cursor and resultset objects:

> curs = exec(dbConn, sqlStr)
>
> rs = fetch(curs)

curs =

```
    Attributes: []
          Data: 0
DatabaseObject: [1x1 database]
      RowLimit: 0
      SQLQuery: 'xxxxxomitxxxx'
       Message: []
          Type: 'Database Cursor Object'
     ResultSet: [1x1 com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet]
        Cursor: [1x1 com.mathworks.toolbox.database.sqlExec]
     Statement: [1x1 com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl]
         Fetch: 0
```

rs =

```
    Attributes: []
          Data: {2497x8 cell}
DatabaseObject: [1x1 database]
      RowLimit: 0
      SQLQuery: 'xxxxxomitxxxx'
       Message: []
          Type: 'Database Cursor Object'
     ResultSet: [1x1 com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet]
        Cursor: [1x1 com.mathworks.toolbox.database.sqlExec]
     Statement: [1x1 com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl]
         Fetch: [1x1 com.mathworks.toolbox.database.fetchTheData]
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote:

> well, by closing the mysql jdbc objects yourself after every fetch you can fix the problem, and not have to extract all of the mathworks code you've used everywhere:
>
> ```
> rs.Statement.close()
> rs.ResultSet.close()
> ```